# React Material UI v5 rendering an element in Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There's a feature that I like to mimic from the link below. When you hover on the image, you'd see Quick View button which show you a summary of the item right below it, as well as take the whole width and height of a row.

[Sample](https://www.epicurious.com/search/chicken)

[Before Quick View click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2sQE.jpg)
[After Quick View click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgJdq.jpg)

Is there any better approach in terms of performance than the one I try below?

```
const [recipeClicked, setRecipeClick] = useState("");
const handleQuickView = (recipeName: string) => {
    console.log("recipeName", recipeName)
    setRecipeClick(recipeName);
  }

<Grid container spacing={4} sx={{ mt: 4, pb: 4 }}>
          {recipes && recipes.map(
            (recipe, idx) => {
              if (++idx % 4 === 0) {
                return (
                  <>
                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={3} key={recipe.title} onClick={() => handleQuickView(recipe.title)}>
                      <RecipeItem recipe={recipe} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Collapse in={true} sx={{ width: '100%', height: `${recipeClicked !== '' ? `300px` : 0}`, background: 'grey', transition:'height 1s ease-in' }}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} lg={12} sx={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                        <Button onClick={() => setRecipeClick('')}>X</Button>
                      </Grid>
                    </Collapse>
                  </>
                )
              } else {
                let recipeToExpand = '';
                for (let i = idx; i < idx + 4; i++) {
                  if (i % 4 === 0) {
                    recipeToExpand = recipes[i - 1]?.title;
                  }
                }
                return (
                  <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={3} key={recipe.title} onClick={() => handleQuickView(recipeToExpand)}>
                    <RecipeItem recipe={recipe} />
                  </Grid>
                )
              }
            }
          )}
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance,
Have a good day!